# Object doesn't find method

Tags: objective-c

I am currently reading the book "Objective C programming" 2nd edition from Big Nerd Ranch and I am stuck since one day on an exercise.

I have an object which should send a message to a method but I get an error that the @interface for the method is not declared.

BNRPortfolio.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class BNRStockHolding;

@interface BNRPortfolio : NSObject

{
    NSMutableArray *_portfolios;
}

@property (nonatomic) double currentValue;

- (void)addStock:(BNRStockHolding *)s;

@end
```

BNRPortfolio.m:

```
#import "BNRPortfolio.h"
#import "BNRStockHolding.h"

@implementation BNRPortfolio

- (double)currentValue:(BNRStockHolding *)holding
{
    return [holding valueInDollars] - [holding costInDollars];
}

- (void)addStock:(BNRStockHolding *)s
{
    // Do we have an array?
    if (!_portfolios) {
        // If not, create one
        _portfolios = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    [_portfolios addObject:s];
}

@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BNRStockHolding.h"
#import "BNRForeignStockHolding.h"
#import "BNRPortfolio.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        BNRStockHolding *holding1 = [[BNRStockHolding alloc] init];

        [holding1 setPurchaseSharePrice:2.30];
        [holding1 setCurrentSharePrice:4.50];
        [holding1 setNumberOfShares:40];
        [holding1 setNameOfHolding:@"holding1"];

        // Everything is good until here and already tested

        BNRPortfolio *portfolio = [[BNRPortfolio alloc] init];
        [portfolio addStock:holding1]; // Throws error of undefined declaration of addStock in    
                                       //BNRPortfolio
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why can I create the object but the object can't find the method which is declared in its header file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't see any strange issue either. Are you sure xCode isn't playing tricks on you? Have you tried building your project despite the error?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted, so I doubt anyone can help.

Comment: Try restarting Xcode.

Comment: That's crazy. I thought my mind is playing tricks on me and that somebody here sees something I don't :-). I can build the project without the last line "[portfolio addStock:holding1]; But not with that. Restart makes no difference either.

End wow, thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: P.S. the other method isn't accessible either if that information helps

Comment: There can be many hidden mistakes - for example, a second header with the same name in your header file path. The best thing is to inspect your preprocessing output.

Comment: I don't know anything about preprocessing yet but I will look up how to do that. Ty

Comment: @Mayo First, inspect your project folders if there are two .h files with the same name. To see the preprocessed file, open main.m and open Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess and scroll to the very end. You should see the `#import` statements expanded. Check the method is really there (as it should be).

Comment: @Sulthan Wow, thank you very much! Problem is solved. There were two .h files and I chose the newer one and now everything builds :-). How did you know that? Genius! I Struggled one day to get it done. Again thanks

Comment: @Mayo Already seen it before :) Added an answer with some explanation.

Comment: @Sulthan thank you. Wanted to vote up but not possible for me yet :|

Answer (score 0):

There were two header files with the same name in the project folder and the compiler was using the older one, in which the method was not declared.

Xcode sees only the files that are added to the project as references. However, the compiler doesn't see which header files were added to the project because it doesn't work with individual headers - it works with the header search path (folders). That means that when it is compiling and it is looking for a `.h` file, it recursively searches folders until it finds it. If there are two files with the same name, it will use the first it finds.